# Saving / Navigating to a file issue

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm sending a request to a server when a button is clicked:

```
private function submitButtonClicked():void
        {
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
            variables.table = tableInput.text;
            var u:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://sasajkl");
            u.data = variables;
            u.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,preparingCompleted);
            loader.load(u);
        }
```

The response from the server is actually a URL address, so my event handler is:

```
private function preparingCompleted(event:Event):void
        {
            var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(event.target.data);
            navigateToURL(request);
        }
```

It used to work in the past, but now due to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277210, it's not working anymore in Chrome. I tried to use `fileReference.download(request,"Report.xls")`, but then I get an error message because the function is not called as a response to a user action (such as a button click).

Does anyone have any idea how I can access the file from the URL address I get from the server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your own [resource link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277210), this is the work around:

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open",url);
```

Comment: Why not?  do you get an error?  Or does nothing happen?   There are some other solutions listed on that page; but the one I grabbed looked like the easiest.